# DiscordJS fetch is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, discord.js

Am attempting to follow a tutorial to use DiscordJS with Typescript, and the tutorial I was following also covers the use of Inversify for dependancy injection.
https://www.cobeisfresh.com/blog/how-to-build-a-free-discord-bot-with-node-js

I've hit an error when trying to get the bot to connect to discord.

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated :) I've been unable to find anything online and I've been told its apparently "not a DJS error", so I have no idea where to look to figure out whats going on.

I have a bot working written in JS which uses commonjs, but this is my first attempt trying to get a discord bot working with typescript and webpack. That makes me think maybe it's something to do with how webpack/typescript is compiling the code for node??

The error I'm getting is this (the /.../ is just me shortening my dev directory url):

```
HTTPError [TypeError]: fetch is not a function
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/.../discord-bot-ts/dist/index.js:16023:15)
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/.../discord-bot-ts/dist/index.js:16027:19)
    at RequestHandler.push (/home/.../discord-bot-ts/dist/index.js:15873:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async WebSocketManager.connect (/home/.../discord-bot-ts/dist/index.js:7799:9)
    at async Client.login (/home/.../discord-bot-ts/dist/index.js:4850:7) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'get',
  path: '/gateway/bot',
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
// main.ts (entry point)
import 'dotenv/config'; // process.env.<key>
import container from './core/inversify.config';
import TYPES from './core/inversify.types';
import Bot from './core/Bot';
import Logger from './helpers/Logger';
 
const bot = container.get<Bot>(TYPES.Bot);
const logger = container.get<Logger>(TYPES.Logger);
 
bot.init().then(() => {
  logger.log('stuff')
})
```

```
// ./core/inversify.config.ts
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Container } from "inversify";
import TYPES from "./inversify.types";
 
import Client from './Client';
import Bot from './Bot';
import Logger from "../helpers/Logger";
 
const container = new Container();
 
container.bind<Client>(TYPES.Client).toConstantValue(new Client());
container.bind<Bot>(TYPES.Bot).to(Bot).inSingletonScope();
container.bind<string>(TYPES.Token).toConstantValue(process.env.TOKEN);
container.bind<Logger>(TYPES.Logger).to(Logger).inSingletonScope();
 
export default container;
```

```
// ./core/inversify.types.ts
export default {
  Client: Symbol.for('client'),
  Bot: Symbol.for('bot'),
  Token: Symbol.for('token'),
  Logger: Symbol.for('logger'),
};
```

```
// ./core/Client.ts
import { Client as DJSClient, Intents } from "discord.js";
import { injectable } from "inversify";
 
@injectable()
class Client extends DJSClient {
  constructor() {
    super({
      intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING,
      ],
      partials: ["CHANNEL", "MESSAGE", "REACTION", "USER", "GUILD_MEMBER"],
      presence: {
        activities: [
          {
            name: "The Network",
            type: "LISTENING",
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
}
 
export default Client;
```

```
// ./core/Bot.ts
import { inject, injectable } from "inversify";
import Client from './Client';
import TYPES from './inversify.types';
 
@injectable()
class DiscordBot {
  private client: Client;
  private readonly token: string;
 
  constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.Client) client: Client,
    @inject(TYPES.Token) token: string
  ){
    this.client = client;
    this.token = token;
  }
 
  init(): Promise<string> {
    return this.client.login(this.token);
  }
}
 
export default DiscordBot;
```

```
// ./helpers/Logger.ts
import { injectable } from "inversify";
 
@injectable()
class Logger {
  log(message: string){
    console.log(message);
  }
}
 
export default Logger;
```

My webpack and ts configs:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const ESLintPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist");

const bot = {
  entry: "./main.ts",
  target: "node",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: ["ts-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  // below because otherwise I get error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' etc
  externals: ['utf-8-validate', 'bufferutil', 'zlib-sync', 'erlpack'],
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(buildPath),
  },
};

module.exports = bot;
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": false,
    "lib": ["es2017", "DOM"],
    "types": ["node", "reflect-metadata"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules", "**/__tests__/*", "**/tests/"]
}
```

The compiled code at line 4850 in the error is this:

```
  /**
   * Logs the client in, establishing a WebSocket connection to Discord.
   * @param {string} [token=this.token] Token of the account to log in with
   * @returns {Promise<string>} Token of the account used
   * @example
   * client.login('my token');
   */
  async login(token = this.token) {
    if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new Error('TOKEN_INVALID');
    this.token = token = token.replace(/^(Bot|Bearer)\s*/i, '');
    this.emit(
      Events.DEBUG,
      `Provided token: ${token
        .split('.')
        .map((val, i) => (i > 1 ? val.replace(/./g, '*') : val))
        .join('.')}`,
    );

    if (this.options.presence) {
      this.options.ws.presence = this.presence._parse(this.options.presence);
    }

    this.emit(Events.DEBUG, 'Preparing to connect to the gateway...');

    try {
      await this.ws.connect(); // line 4850
      return this.token;
    } catch (error) {
      this.destroy();
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

---

Edited to add code at line 16023 per comment request

```js
async execute(request) {
    /*
     * After calculations have been done, pre-emptively stop further requests
     * Potentially loop until this task can run if e.g. the global rate limit is hit twice
     */
    while (this.limited) {
      const isGlobal = this.globalLimited;
      let limit, timeout, delayPromise;

      if (isGlobal) {
        // Set the variables based on the global rate limit
        limit = this.manager.globalLimit;
        timeout = this.manager.globalReset + this.manager.client.options.restTimeOffset - Date.now();
      } else {
        // Set the variables based on the route-specific rate limit
        limit = this.limit;
        timeout = this.reset + this.manager.client.options.restTimeOffset - Date.now();
      }

      if (this.manager.client.listenerCount(RATE_LIMIT)) {
        /**
         * Emitted when the client hits a rate limit while making a request
         * @event BaseClient#rateLimit
         * @param {RateLimitData} rateLimitData Object containing the rate limit info
         */
        this.manager.client.emit(RATE_LIMIT, {
          timeout,
          limit,
          method: request.method,
          path: request.path,
          route: request.route,
          global: isGlobal,
        });
      }

      if (isGlobal) {
        // If this is the first task to reach the global timeout, set the global delay
        if (!this.manager.globalDelay) {
          // The global delay function should clear the global delay state when it is resolved
          this.manager.globalDelay = this.globalDelayFor(timeout);
        }
        delayPromise = this.manager.globalDelay;
      } else {
        delayPromise = sleep(timeout);
      }

      // Determine whether a RateLimitError should be thrown
      await this.onRateLimit(request, limit, timeout, isGlobal); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop

      // Wait for the timeout to expire in order to avoid an actual 429
      await delayPromise; // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
    }

    // As the request goes out, update the global usage information
    if (!this.manager.globalReset || this.manager.globalReset < Date.now()) {
      this.manager.globalReset = Date.now() + 1_000;
      this.manager.globalRemaining = this.manager.globalLimit;
    }
    this.manager.globalRemaining--;

    /**
     * Represents a request that will or has been made to the Discord API
     * @typedef {Object} APIRequest
     * @property {HTTPMethod} method The HTTP method used in this request
     * @property {string} path The full path used to make the request
     * @property {string} route The API route identifying the rate limit for this request
     * @property {Object} options Additional options for this request
     * @property {number} retries The number of times this request has been attempted
     */

    if (this.manager.client.listenerCount(API_REQUEST)) {
      /**
       * Emitted before every API request.
       * This event can emit several times for the same request, e.g. when hitting a rate limit.
       * <info>This is an informational event that is emitted quite frequently,
       * it is highly recommended to check `request.path` to filter the data.</info>
       * @event BaseClient#apiRequest
       * @param {APIRequest} request The request that is about to be sent
       */
      this.manager.client.emit(API_REQUEST, {
        method: request.method,
        path: request.path,
        route: request.route,
        options: request.options,
        retries: request.retries,
      });
    }

    // Perform the request
    let res;
    try {
      res = await request.make();
    } catch (error) {
      // Retry the specified number of times for request abortions
      if (request.retries === this.manager.client.options.retryLimit) {
        // THIS IS LINE 16023
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
      }

      request.retries++;
      // THIS IS LINE 16027
      return this.execute(request);
    }

    if (this.manager.client.listenerCount(API_RESPONSE)) {
      /**
       * Emitted after every API request has received a response.
       * This event does not necessarily correlate to completion of the request, e.g. when hitting a rate limit.
       * <info>This is an informational event that is emitted quite frequently,
       * it is highly recommended to check `request.path` to filter the data.</info>
       * @event BaseClient#apiResponse
       * @param {APIRequest} request The request that triggered this response
       * @param {Response} response The response received from the Discord API
       */
      this.manager.client.emit(
        API_RESPONSE,
        {
          method: request.method,
          path: request.path,
          route: request.route,
          options: request.options,
          retries: request.retries,
        },
        res.clone(),
      );
    }

    let sublimitTimeout;
    if (res.headers) {
      const serverDate = res.headers.get('date');
      const limit = res.headers.get('x-ratelimit-limit');
      const remaining = res.headers.get('x-ratelimit-remaining');
      const reset = res.headers.get('x-ratelimit-reset');
      const resetAfter = res.headers.get('x-ratelimit-reset-after');
      this.limit = limit ? Number(limit) : Infinity;
      this.remaining = remaining ? Number(remaining) : 1;

      this.reset = reset || resetAfter ? calculateReset(reset, resetAfter, serverDate) : Date.now();

      // https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/182
      if (!resetAfter && request.route.includes('reactions')) {
        this.reset = new Date(serverDate).getTime() - getAPIOffset(serverDate) + 250;
      }

      // Handle retryAfter, which means we have actually hit a rate limit
      let retryAfter = res.headers.get('retry-after');
      retryAfter = retryAfter ? Number(retryAfter) * 1_000 : -1;
      if (retryAfter > 0) {
        // If the global rate limit header is set, that means we hit the global rate limit
        if (res.headers.get('x-ratelimit-global')) {
          this.manager.globalRemaining = 0;
          this.manager.globalReset = Date.now() + retryAfter;
        } else if (!this.localLimited) {
          /*
           * This is a sublimit (e.g. 2 channel name changes/10 minutes) since the headers don't indicate a
           * route-wide rate limit. Don't update remaining or reset to avoid rate limiting the whole
           * endpoint, just set a reset time on the request itself to avoid retrying too soon.
           */
          sublimitTimeout = retryAfter;
        }
      }
    }

    // Count the invalid requests
    if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403 || res.status === 429) {
      if (!invalidCountResetTime || invalidCountResetTime < Date.now()) {
        invalidCountResetTime = Date.now() + 1_000 * 60 * 10;
        invalidCount = 0;
      }
      invalidCount++;

      const emitInvalid =
        this.manager.client.listenerCount(INVALID_REQUEST_WARNING) &&
        this.manager.client.options.invalidRequestWarningInterval > 0 &&
        invalidCount % this.manager.client.options.invalidRequestWarningInterval === 0;
      if (emitInvalid) {
        /**
         * @typedef {Object} InvalidRequestWarningData
         * @property {number} count Number of invalid requests that have been made in the window
         * @property {number} remainingTime Time in ms remaining before the count resets
         */

        /**
         * Emitted periodically when the process sends invalid requests to let users avoid the
         * 10k invalid requests in 10 minutes threshold that causes a ban
         * @event BaseClient#invalidRequestWarning
         * @param {InvalidRequestWarningData} invalidRequestWarningData Object containing the invalid request info
         */
        this.manager.client.emit(INVALID_REQUEST_WARNING, {
          count: invalidCount,
          remainingTime: invalidCountResetTime - Date.now(),
        });
      }
    }

    // Handle 2xx and 3xx responses
    if (res.ok) {
      // Nothing wrong with the request, proceed with the next one
      return parseResponse(res);
    }

    // Handle 4xx responses
    if (res.status >= 400 && res.status < 500) {
      // Handle ratelimited requests
      if (res.status === 429) {
        const isGlobal = this.globalLimited;
        let limit, timeout;
        if (isGlobal) {
          // Set the variables based on the global rate limit
          limit = this.manager.globalLimit;
          timeout = this.manager.globalReset + this.manager.client.options.restTimeOffset - Date.now();
        } else {
          // Set the variables based on the route-specific rate limit
          limit = this.limit;
          timeout = this.reset + this.manager.client.options.restTimeOffset - Date.now();
        }

        this.manager.client.emit(
          DEBUG,
          `Hit a 429 while executing a request.
    Global  : ${isGlobal}
    Method  : ${request.method}
    Path    : ${request.path}
    Route   : ${request.route}
    Limit   : ${limit}
    Timeout : ${timeout}ms
    Sublimit: ${sublimitTimeout ? `${sublimitTimeout}ms` : 'None'}`,
        );

        await this.onRateLimit(request, limit, timeout, isGlobal);

        // If caused by a sublimit, wait it out here so other requests on the route can be handled
        if (sublimitTimeout) {
          await sleep(sublimitTimeout);
        }
        return this.execute(request);
      }

      // Handle possible malformed requests
      let data;
      try {
        data = await parseResponse(res);
      } catch (err) {
        throw new HTTPError(err.message, err.constructor.name, err.status, request);
      }

      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
    }

    // Handle 5xx responses
    if (res.status >= 500 && res.status < 600) {
      // Retry the specified number of times for possible serverside issues
      if (request.retries === this.manager.client.options.retryLimit) {
        throw new HTTPError(res.statusText, res.constructor.name, res.status, request);
      }

      request.retries++;
      return this.execute(request);
    }

    // Fallback in the rare case a status code outside the range 200..=599 is returned
    return null;
  }
```

---

Edit 2: Tested stripped back code, I get the same error with the following code in my main.ts file

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import { Client, Intents } from "discord.js";
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: Can you post code at line 16023 of index.js and surrounding code

Comment: @Kaspr edited the post with requested code. Commented in the code // THIS IS LINE xxxx to identify the offending lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though discordjs (or discord itself) does not support or recommend the use of webpack.

I'm unsure if this is the source of the issue, but I have things working now by stripping out webpack and just using the TypeScript compiler to build the code

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/4710#issuecomment-743762394

I'll leave the question open for a bit though just in case this error is something unrelated and someone knows a fix :)